# Proper Notation of Posterior

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to determine the proper way to describe a posterior distribution using probability notation. That is:

$$f_{\theta|Y=y}(\theta_0)=\lim_{\Delta\theta_0\to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(\theta \in (\theta,\theta+\Delta \theta_0)|Y=y)}{\Delta_0}\propto \lim_{\Delta\theta_0\to 0,\Delta_y \to 0}\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y\in (y,y+\Delta_y)|\theta \in (\theta,\theta+\Delta \theta_0))\mathbb{P}(\theta \in (\theta,\theta+\Delta \theta_0))}{\Delta_0\Delta_y}$$

I am pretty sure my notation is wrong. Can anyone explain what is the proper notation.

Comment: Different authors use various notations, sometimes influenced by context or intended audience. So it seems there is no accepted standard. For my purposes I like to see some hint that the posterior is a distribution on a parameter (in your case $\theta)$ given data $x.$ Your notation does that.